# Assume that the conjugate of f(z) is analytic in $\Omega$. Then f is a constant function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I know that the conjugate of f(z)=u-vi and the CR for this is $u_{x}=-v_{y}$ and $u_{y}=v_{x}$.  I don't know what property I need to invoke to get f to be a constant function.  Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need that $f$ is analytic, otherwise the result is not true (take $f(z) = \bar{z}$ and $\Omega = \Bbb C$ for example). The CR equations for $f$ are $u_x = v_y$, $u_y = -v_x$. Combining that with the equations you have above, we deduce $u_x = v_y = -u_x$ and $u_y = -v_x = -u_y$, which imply $u_x = u_y = 0$. Since $\Omega$ is connected, $u$ is constant. Similarly $v_x = v_y = 0$, so since $\Omega$ is connected, $v$ is constant. Therefore $f = u + iv$ is constant.